# Nikon lens zoom stuck

Tags: nikon

i have problem with my Nikon D90 18-105mm lens. When the lens is installed in camera when zooming out it goes up to 24 mm and can’t go to 18mm. When i remove the lens from camera it works perfectly and goes from 18 up to 105 mm with no problems. Does anyone know what can be the problem

When i get to 24mm and try to go forward to 18mm it seems physically restricted but only when the lens is installed in camera otherwise when removed the lens moves freely from 105 to 18 mm with no strange sounds. Also if i adjust the lens at 18mm before installing in camera, i install it and move it towards 105mm then at 24mm i hear a click sound

Comment: Please add more details. Describe what happens when you get to 24mm, and when you try to go wider toward 18mm. Does it seem to be physically restricted from going wider? Is there any sort of grinding or un-smooth behavior? When you say it can't go wider than 24mm, is that the position you see on the lens's zoom ring marks, or is that observed in photos'  `EXIF` data? The more descriptive you are, the better we might be able to help. Thanks.